# ἀναγκάζω and ἐκβάλλω, ‘compel’ and ‘forcefully cast’ or ‘drive’ or ‘thrust’

Tags: greek, matthew, luke

Matt 9:38 and Luke 14:23 are two different passages with two different Greek words, but it seems the idea of force is quite similar. Both are allegories Jesus told. In the one, God as banquet host has his servants compel newly-invited people to come to his prepared feast. In the other, God as field owner is begged to cast or drive or thrust his laborers to work bringing in the ripe harvest. Both have a sense of force to it, a nuance of urgency and pressure. As if being taken by the shoulders and firmly brought. Do these different Greek words have this intensity, or am I misapplying them?

> Matt 9:38 - Beseech the Lord of the harvest, therefore, that He might
> send out [ἐκβάλλω] workmen into His harvest."
>
> Luke 14:23 - And the master said to the servant, 'Go out into the
> highways and hedges and compel [ἀναγκάζω] them to come in, so that my
> house may be filled.

Comment: @curiousdanni, thanks so much for your edit help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matt 9:38 and Luke 14:23 are two
different  passages with two
different Greek words, but it seems
the idea of force is quite similar.

... am I misapplying them?
```

I believe so.

The only correspondence I see in these verses, from different parables (one is merely a metaphor in a statement), is in the go/send out.

> ... to send out (ἐκβάλῃ) workers into his harvest field.
>
> Go out (Ἔξελθε) to the roads and country lanes ...

Different words, different action. One sends, the other goes.

#### Harvest workers.

> Then he said to his disciples, “The harvest is plentiful but the workers are few. Ask the Lord of the harvest, therefore, to send out workers into his harvest field.”
>
> Matthew 9:37-38 NIV

> He told them, “The harvest is plentiful, but the workers are few. Ask the Lord of the harvest, therefore, to send out workers into his harvest field."
>
> Luke 10:2 NIV

There is no forceful intent there.
The closest would be ἐκβάλλω, to cast out.
Rotherham has :

> That he would ***thrust forth*** labourers ...

> ... that he would ***thrust forth***, labourers ...

However this is not guaranteed :

> He calls his own sheep by name and leads them out. When he has brought out (ἐκβάλῃ) all his own ...
>
> John 10:3-4 NIV

Clearly not forceful, rather the opposite.

#### Banquet guests.

> The king was ***enraged***. He sent his army and destroyed those murderers and burned their city.
>
> So go to the street corners and invite to the banquet anyone you find.
>
> Matthew 22:7,9 NIV

> Then the owner of the house became ***angry*** and ordered his servant, 'Go out quickly into the streets and alleys of the town and bring in the poor, the crippled, the blind and the lame.'
>
> Then the master told his servant, 'Go out to the roads and country lanes and **compel** them to come in, so that my house will be full.'
>
> Luke 14:21,23

While there is ὀργίζω in both, Luke is the only account, to my eyes, that has the idea of ἀναγκάζω or "urging" them to come in.
Ultimately a very different issue to ejecting, or thrusting out, or ordering, those who work for you.

I think you're looking for a connection that isn't there.

Comment: yes Rotherham’s interpretation of the word as thrust is what I had in mind, but couldn’t find. Plus I’d seen the word interpretated elsewhere as cast, but usually in regard to a context such as exorcising an evil spirit. I was unsure if I was reaching or not, thanks so much for the clarification. I’m a bit disappointed I’m mistaken, but would rather not misread the meaning. I’m grateful for your help, thank you.

Comment: @Rachel Glad I could help. Rotherham is my go to probably every time I want to check anything usage wise. I find him to be incredibly faithful to the original for the most part. And often, as in this case, he really nails stuff every one else ignores. They see what he saw, he just respects us enough to take a chance. Good guy.

Comment: here’s my train of thought, for fun. My connection between the two different verses is that both are allegories of the gospel, from different perspectives. God is the banquet host and field owner. Those tasked with evangelism are the servants and field laborers. However the one story describes two sets of people, the insiders (Israel?) who reject the gospel invitation and the outsiders (Samaritan’s and gentiles?) who recieve it. The other story describes only one set of people, those ready to recieve the gospel. So I was curious about the meanings and why, of compel and sent.

Comment: @Rachel I think that's absolutely correct. While the harvest does include the tares, there's the sense here of the wheat. It's a succinct, broad, positive statement. In the king's son's wedding banquet we have those rejecting the invitation being primarily the scribes and pharisees, the 'poor, the crippled, the blind and the lame' otoh being readily found in contrast in his ministry who worshipped him, finally those from the 'broad way' being the gentiles, that sheet lowered from heaven, by his father, after Israel, elite and outcast had their shot, their still being plenty of room. John 14:2

Comment: @DavianWalker, oh that is interesting. I had never considered that the Scribes and Pharisees might have been who Jesus was referencing as ignoring the banquet. Food for thought, pun intended. That perhaps the banquet alluded to the son’s wedding feast -wow. Rich things to think about, thanks so much.

Comment: @Rachel Jesus way with parables is legendary. I just noticed this : "The king was enraged. He sent his army and destroyed those murderers and burned their city." So after the jewish elite rejected the son's wedding, he burned their city. Funny about that. The father put all things into his hand and he knew what was the outcome.

Comment: I was a little confused until I realized you are referencing Matt 22:1-14 which wasn’t in my original question, yet it fits very well as a third elaboration by Jesus from yet another perspective of that theme. A bot is scolding me for chatting with you too much here, but I’ve really enjoyed it. Cheers.